# how to access nested json array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

this is my code and need to retrieve some parts of json data

this my json data,in this i need to retrieve topology-id,node-id,tp-id which is in nested json array so write some code just check that once, and i am very new to angularjs.so help me out with this issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="list">
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="data in network-topology">
        <li >{{data.topology}}</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="data1 in topology">
        <li >{{data1.topology-id}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="data2 in node">
        <li >{{data2.node-id}}</li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="data3 in termination-point">
        <li >{{data3.tp-id}}</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('list', ['base64']);
app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $base64) {

$http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  }).success(function(tdata) {
 $scope.network-topology= tdata.network-topology;
 $scope.topology= tdata.topology;
 $scope.topology-id = tdata.topology-id;
    $scope.node-id = tdata.node-id;
 $scope.tp-id = tdata.tp-id;
    $scope.topology= [];
    $scope.node= [];
    $scope.termination-point= [];
    angular.forEach(tdata.network-topology, function(network-topology, index){
               angular.forEach(network-topology.topology, function(topology, index){
           angular.forEach(network-topology.topology.node, function(node, index) {
                   angular.forEach(network-topology.topology.node.termination-point, function(termination-point, index){
                                                 $scope.termination-point.push(termination-point);
             });
      });
      });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your json data `tdata`

Comment: {
"network-topology":{ 
                     "topology":[{"topology-id":"flow:1", 
                                   "node":[
                                            { "node-id":"openflow:1",
                                              "termination-point":[
                                                     {"tp-id":"openflow:1:2",
                                                      "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref":"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes

Answer (score 1):

is this the complete  code, once check this and let me know

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="list">
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<div ng-repeat='data1 in data["network-topology"].topology'>
          {{data1["topology-id"]}}
            <div ng-repeat='data2 in data1.node'>
              {{data2["node-id"]}}

            <div ng-repeat='data3 in data2["termination-point"]'>
              {{data3["tp-id"]}}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
angular.module('list', []).controller('ListCtrl', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.jsonData={
"network-topology": {
  "topology": [{
    "topology-id": "flow:1",
    "node": [{
      "node-id": "openflow:1",
      "termination-point": [{
        "tp-id": "openflow:1:2",
        "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-re‌​f": "/opendaylight-in‌​ventory:nodes"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using "-" in attributes to become subtraction in angularjs so,suggest to user underscore(network-topology instead of network_topology)

```
$rootScope.jsonData={
"network-topology": {
  "topology": [{
    "topology-id": "flow:1",
    "node": [{
      "node-id": "openflow:1",
      "termination-point": [{
        "tp-id": "openflow:1:2",
        "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-re‌​f": "/opendaylight-in‌​ventory:nodes"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
}
```

view

```
<div ng-repeat='data1 in data["network-topology"].topology'>
          {{data1["topology-id"]}}
            <div ng-repeat='data2 in data1.node'>
              {{data2["node-id"]}}

            <div ng-repeat='data3 in data2["termination-point"]'>
              {{data3["tp-id"]}}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

output:

```
flow:1
openflow:1
openflow:1:2
```

Comment: but the json data i have to get from the url, and the json data can be increased time to time because it is a network configuration

Comment: just copied your response in a variable and worked on it to show output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be your final code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="list">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='data1 in data["network-topology"].topology'>
          {{data1["topology-id"]}}
            <div ng-repeat='data2 in data1.node'>
              {{data2["node-id"]}}

            <div ng-repeat='data3 in data2["termination-point"]'>
              {{data3["tp-id"]}}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('list', ['base64']);
app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $base64) {

   $http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('admin' + ':' + 'admin');

 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://10.132.32.212:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 }).success(function(tdata) {
   $scope.data= tdata;
  
      });
     });
 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i am not getting anything , the empty browser is displaying

Comment: did you get any response in the $scope.data

Comment: i am getting the data

Comment: copy the data here

Comment: its very huge data

Comment: give me your mail id i will send

Comment: kesariharish.789@gmail.com